# PrimeNG Angular MenuItem Moving To Right

Tags: css, angular, primeng, menuitem

I am trying to create a menubar using primeng where some menu items need to be on the left and others need to be on the right.  Using  doesn't work well since the component isn't responsive when using on a small screen.  Using CSS, how would you go about with moving a menu item to the right on the toolbar? Using the code below, I want to move the search and profile to the right side of the screen. I've tried float: right and text-align: right without any luck.  Any suggestions?

TS file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  items!: MenuItem[];

  title = 'chartproject';
  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
        {
            label: 'Charts',
            items:[{label: 'Line Chart',  routerLink: 'chart', icon: 'pi pi-chart-line'},
                   {label: 'Bar Chart', routerLink: 'chart/bar', icon:'pi pi-chart-bar'}]
            
        },
        {
          label: 'Maps',
          items:[{label: 'Maps',  routerLink: 'maps', icon: 'pi pi-map'}
                 ]
          
      },
        {
            label: 'Edit',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-pencil',
            items: [
                {label: 'Delete', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-trash'},
                {label: 'Refresh', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-refresh'}
            ],
            disabled:true
        },
        {
            label:'Search'
        },
        {
            label:'Profile',
            icon:'pi pi-times',
            
        }
    ];
}
}
```

HTML file

```
<p-menubar [model]="items">
</p-menubar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found a resolution.  I wasn't aware that the menubar is simply a flexbox.  First you will need to add css so that the flexbox fills the width of the page.  You can do this by adding the below css.  Also would need to either add style: {'margin-left': 'auto'} or styleClass ='p-ml-auto' if you have primeflex to the ts file.

css

```
:host ::ng-deep p-menubarsub {
    width: 100%;
}
```

ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  items!: MenuItem[];

  title = 'chartproject';
  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
        {
            label: 'Charts',
            items:[{label: 'Line Chart',  routerLink: 'chart', icon: 'pi pi-chart-line'},
                   {label: 'Bar Chart', routerLink: 'chart/bar', icon:'pi pi-chart-bar'}]
            
        },
        {
          label: 'Maps',
          items:[{label: 'Maps',  routerLink: 'maps', icon: 'pi pi-map'}
                 ]
          
      },
        {
            label: 'Edit',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-pencil',
            items: [
                {label: 'Delete', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-trash'},
                {label: 'Refresh', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-refresh'}
            ],
            disabled:true
        },
        {
            label:'Search', styleClass:'p-ml-auto'

        },
        {
            label:'Profile',
            icon:'pi pi-times',
            
        }
    ];
}
}
```